# How to identify the last view in a single view controller?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am using 3 views in a single view controller with same `height/width` and `hiding/showing` as per the need in `objective c`.
In this scenario I want to get the last view which we are showing, because I have to manage that condition while animating the views.

```
if (selectedBtnIndex == 1) 
{ 
  [_viewForTripDetail setHidden:NO]; 
  [_viewForReceipt setHidden:YES];  
  [_viewForGetHelp setHidden:YES];  
  CATransition transition = [[CATransition alloc] init]; 
  transition.duration = 0.2; 
  transition.type = kCATransitionPush; 
  transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;   
  [_viewForTripDetail.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];  
  _const_leadingViewBelowBtn.constant = _btnTripDetail.frame.origin.x+10; 
   flagTripDetailOpen = (int)1;
```

please help me to find the last view which was shown on screen.

Thank you.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: thanks for reply. Actually I am managing it by click of buttons, that means there are three buttons, while clicking on each button, seperate view will shown and rest get hide.

Below is my code -

Comment: if (selectedBtnIndex == 1) {
        [_viewForTripDetail setHidden:NO];
        [_viewForReceipt setHidden:YES];
        [_viewForGetHelp setHidden:YES];
        CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc] init];
        transition.duration = 0.2;
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [_viewForTripDetail.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

        _const_leadingViewBelowBtn.constant = _btnTripDetail.frame.origin.x+10;
        flagTripDetailOpen = (int*)1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like,

```
if (yourView.isHidden) {

    NSLog(@"view is hidden");
}
else{

    NSLog(@"view is not hidden");
}
```

Or

You can take one flag also and maintain that flag when you show or hide your view!

Comment: Thanks for the reply and valuable time,
Yes I have managed it by maintaining the flag and the selected index of button, and now its working. :)